# About using retain , release in ARC enabled code

Tags: ios5

This is about ARC in IOS 5.

Suppose it is ARC enabled and I still use retain release etc in code , are there any risks ?? or will it be handled automatically ??

I know that ARC can be avoided for specific files. But in this case I have not done anything to remove ARC on this file. This file is now a mixup ( with release for some allocations and without release for some allocations ).

What are the risks expected in such an environment?
Thanks for any help !

--mia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `retain` or `release` in ARC enabled code. It's simply not allowed - the compiler will error out. If you are not explicitly indicating to the compiler that a file should not be compiled with ARC enabled (using the `-fno-objc-arc` flag) and you call `release` your code won't compile.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh, that was a silly question then :). Sorry for that . I actually thought I have checked ARC in the sample project . Now I rechecked in settings and it was disabled. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose it is ARC enabled and I still use retain release etc in code

You can't. You will get a compiler error if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Mia, that is actually untrue. If you compile from the command line using Clang and tell it to use ARC with the flag `-fobjc-arc` you can get away with [object release], etc. It appears to be a xCode thing that blocks the use of these memory management calls.

However, like lxt was suggesting you will **NOT** be able to call release / retain if ARC is enabled in an xCode project unless you explicitly add the `-fno-objc-arc` as a compiler flag for the file in your project the requires it.